# How to create a sitemap page for my blogger blog

Tags: javascript

I have found a snippet from a template which I want to implement in my blog. I have to put this code in my template so that when I create a new page in blogger and write [sitemap] on it, the page becomes the sitemap of my blog. Please help me to do so. Here is the code:

```
if (static_page_text === "[sitemap]") {
    var postbody = $('.static_page .post-body');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(dataZ) {
            var blogLabels = [];
            for (var t = 0; t &lt; dataZ.feed.category.length; t++) {
                blogLabels.push(dataZ.feed.category[t].term)
            }
            var blogLabels = blogLabels.join('/');
            postbody.html('<div class="siteLabel"></div>');
            $('.static_page .post-body .siteLabel').text(blogLabels);
            var splabel = $(".siteLabel").text().split("/");
            var splabels = "";
            for (get = 0; get &lt; splabel.length; ++get) {
                splabels += "<span>" + splabel[get] + "</span>"
            }
            $(".siteLabel").html(splabels);
            $('.siteLabel span').each(function() {
                var mapLabel = $(this);
                var mapLabel_text = $(this).text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + mapLabel_text + "?alt=json-in-script",
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var posturl = "";
                        var htmlcode = '<div class="mapa">';
                        for (var i = 0; i &lt; data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j &lt; data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                                if (data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                                    posturl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                            var posttitle = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
                            var author = data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
                            var get_date = data.feed.entry[i].published.$t,
                                year = get_date.substring(0, 4),
                                month = get_date.substring(5, 7),
                                day = get_date.substring(8, 10),
                                date = text_month[parseInt(month, 10)] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
                            var tag = data.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
                            var content = data.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
                            var $content = $('<div>').html(content);
                            var src2 = data.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                            htmlcode += '<div class="mapapost"><div class="map-thumb"><div class="map-img"><a href="' + posturl + '" style="background:url(' + src2 + ') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"/></div></div><h3 class="wrp-titulo"><a href="' + posturl + '">' + posttitle + '</a></h3><div class="map-meta"><span class="p-author">' + author + '</span><span class="p-date">' + date + '</span></div></div>'
                        }
                        htmlcode += '</div>';
                        mapLabel.replaceWith('<div class="mapasite"><h2>' + mapLabel_text + '<span class="botao"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span></h2>' + htmlcode + '</div>');
                        $(document).on('click', '.mapasite h2', function() {
                            $(this).parent('.mapasite').addClass('active');
                            $(this).find('.botao .fa').removeClass('fa-plus-circle').addClass('fa-minus-circle');
                        });
                        $(document).on('click', '.mapasite.active h2', function() {
                            $(this).parent('.mapasite').removeClass('active');
                            $(this).find('.botao .fa').addClass('fa-plus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the full code for Blogger use: In the template, search for the `</body>` tag  and just above it paste the following HTML Coding.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
            //<![CDATA[
var static_page_text = $.trim($('.static_page .post-body').text());
if (static_page_text === "[sitemap]") {
    var postbody = $('.static_page .post-body');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(dataZ) {
            var blogLabels = [];
            for (var t = 0; t < dataZ.feed.category.length; t++) {
                blogLabels.push(dataZ.feed.category[t].term)
            }
            var blogLabels = blogLabels.join('/');
            postbody.html('<div class="siteLabel"></div>');
            $('.static_page .post-body .siteLabel').text(blogLabels);
            var splabel = $(".siteLabel").text().split("/");
            var splabels = "";
            for (get = 0; get < splabel.length; ++get) {
                splabels += "<span>" + splabel[get] + "</span>"
            }
            $(".siteLabel").html(splabels);
            $('.siteLabel span').each(function() {
                var mapLabel = $(this);
                var mapLabel_text = $(this).text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + mapLabel_text + "?alt=json-in-script",
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var posturl = "";
                        var htmlcode = '<div class="mapa">';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                                if (data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel == "alternate") {
                                    posturl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                            var posttitle = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
                            var author = data.feed.entry[i].author[0].name.$t;
                            var get_date = data.feed.entry[i].published.$t,
                                year = get_date.substring(0, 4),
                                month = get_date.substring(5, 7),
                                day = get_date.substring(8, 10),
                                date = text_month[parseInt(month, 10)] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
                            var tag = data.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
                            var content = data.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
                            var $content = $('<div>').html(content);
                            var src2 = data.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
                            htmlcode += '<div class="mapapost"><div class="map-thumb"><div class="map-img"><a href="' + posturl + '" style="background:url(' + src2 + ') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"/></div></div><h3 class="wrp-titulo"><a href="' + posturl + '">' + posttitle + '</a></h3><div class="map-meta"><span class="p-author">' + author + '</span><span class="p-date">' + date + '</span></div></div>'
                        }
                        htmlcode += '</div>';
                        mapLabel.replaceWith('<div class="mapasite"><h2>' + mapLabel_text + '<span class="botao"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></span></h2>' + htmlcode + '</div>');
                        $(document).on('click', '.mapasite h2', function() {
                            $(this).parent('.mapasite').addClass('active');
                            $(this).find('.botao .fa').removeClass('fa-plus-circle').addClass('fa-minus-circle');
                        });
                        $(document).on('click', '.mapasite.active h2', function() {
                            $(this).parent('.mapasite').removeClass('active');
                            $(this).find('.botao .fa').addClass('fa-plus-circle').removeClass('fa-minus-circle');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
            //]]>
</script>
```

CSS Code : In the template, search for the `</body>` tag  and just above it paste the following HTML Coding.

```css
 .mapasite {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        background-color: #F8F8F8
    }
    .mapasite.active .mapa {
        display: block
    }
    .mapasite .mapa {
        display: none
    }
    .mapasite h2 {
        background-color: #EEE;
        color: $(primary.color);
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 700
    }
    .mapasite h2 .botao {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.2em
    }
    .botao .fa-minus-circle {
        color: #f30
    }
    .mapapost {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: #FFF
    }
    .mapa {
        padding: 40px
    }
    .map-thumb {
        background-color: #F0F0F0;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        width: 65px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left
    }
    .map-img {
        width: 65px;
        height: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 2px
    }
    .map-thumb a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease-out!important
    }
    .map-thumb a:hover {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-1.5deg)!important;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-1.5deg)!important;
        transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-1.5deg)!important;
        transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out!important;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease-out!important
    }
    .mapapost .wrp-titulo {
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.3em;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-bottom: 5px
    }
    .mapapost .wrp-titulo a {

    }
    .mapapost .wrp-titulo a:hover {
        color: #f30;
        text-decoration: underline
    }
    .map-meta {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .mapasite h2 .botao {
        float: right
    }
```

Go to your blogger dashboard > Pages > Add New Page.
On the new page content after adding the page title and hiding the comments using options, add the following code in the page content area.

Refer to my blog on the same [Generate XML Sitemap](https://mukeshmali.com/generate-xml-sitemap-for-blogger)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.